# Saving dictionary keys as strings

Tags: python, dictionary

I have following dictionary:

```
OrderedDict([(u'b1', OrderedDict([(u'ip', u'199.0.0.1'), (u'port', u'1122')])),
             (u'b2', OrderedDict([(u'ip', u'199.0.0.1'), (u'port', u'1123')]))])
```

I want to create a string that take keys from the dictionary and join them but also put `:` in between, so the result will be

```
(b1:b2)
```

there can be a lot of keys in the dictionary. Can somebody help me out with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `str.join`

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> dic =  OrderedDict([(u'b1', OrderedDict([(u'ip', u'199.0.0.1'), (u'port', u'1122')])), (u'b2', OrderedDict([(u'ip', u'199.0.0.1'), (u'port', u'1123')]))])
>>> ":".join(dic)
u'b1:b2'
```

Comment: Things like this is why I love Python! :) Great solution.

Comment: Nothing more to see here. Move on. There is only one answer -- and this one is it. +1

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I don't think you should even suggest `encode`ing back to Python 2.7 `str` this, there is no reason to convert back, unicode is default in Python 3 so we shouldn't be steering People away from it like it's an annoying `u` that we need to remove whenever we see it.

Comment: @jamylak I added that part only because python beginners find it weird, though you've a valid points so I've removed that part from my answer.